# AJAX request loading resources again

Tags: html, jquery, dom

I'm coding a page for an online store so there are quite a few images (thumbnail and fullsize for each product). 
I'm using a preloader for all the page resources (images and fonts), however every time I do a jquery ajax request, it loads everything again.
I've tried adding the resources to the window but it did not solve this.
Here's my code:

```
$.getJSON(ajax,{type:t,group:g},function(data){
    var h = '';
    for(var d in data){
        h += '<div class="product" name="'+data[d].name+'" desc="'+data[d].desc+'" photo="'+data[d].photo+'" parent="'+data[d].id+'">';
        h += '<img src="'+data[d].thumb+'"/><span>'+data[d].name+'</span>';
        h += '</div>';
    }
    $('#product_list').html(h);
 });
var load = ['http://mysite/img/background.jpg',
        'http://mysite/img/header.jpg',
        'http://mysite/img/logo.png',
        'http://mysite/css/tipografia/hotel_coral.ttf',
        'http://mysite/css/tipografia/BEBAS.ttf'];
$(document).ready(function(){

    loadAll(load);
}

function loadAll(a) {
    while (a.length > 0) {
    var item = a.shift();
    $.preload(item);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**Added the code that loads calls the loadall function.

Here's a link to a pic of the requests
[network activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x67hN.jpg)

And a link to the preloader
[dreamerslab](http://dreamerslab.com/en/works#main=1)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think we are going to need to see a bit more code than this. Perhaps the code that calls loadAll, or if theres not too much whole whole js file?

Comment: Done, added the code in the edit...thanks @binarysmacker

Comment: It seems like actually that your generating ajax responces that contain all previous data + the new result. So maybe try ONLY asking for the specific new section of data and then use .append() to add that onto the end if the existing content in the div, instead of replacing everything each time.....does that make sense?

Comment: @binarysmacker thanks for the help! I did change the code so instead of loading everything with each request, I just use PHP to get the relevant products from the start, then I use jquery to show/hide the relevant div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has that fixed the problem?. It might still be a good idea to use ajax to build the list instead of getting everything and hiding for performance sake.

Comment: It did fix the problem. It's not a big page, therefore performance is not really affected by this solution, so once again, thanks.